# How to exit a Docker-based GitHub Self-Hosted Runner

Tags: docker, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

Hi I am running a load of GH self-hosted runners in Docker containers.  These are running in a Nomad instance on my Ubuntu VM.

As Nomad acts as a process supervisor starting containers which are not running if it detects such, in order to ensure a clean working environment for every run, I want the container to be destroyed/exited as soon as the actions runner in the container has completed the run triggered by the API call (or commit to main) in the repo.

Before I start fiddling with flowery solutions, as I couldn't find any specific answers to this online, I thought I'd check here in case someone can offer a solution. Nothing in the self-hosted runner docs that I could find suggested an answer - the design appears to be to run all the time, but I want it destroyed after the run.

As the runner program in the container does not exit on job end, I'm thinking I'd need to either augment the `start.sh` script for the runner container to self-kill it's own container processes (which I tried a few ways with limited success) or write a shim container/process to work with an augmented `start.sh` in the runner container which writes a file or similar somewhere on the host or checks the repo somehow which the shim can use to know the run finished internally and kill the container from outside.  None of that sounds appealing.

Thanks IA